# How to find/calculate future schedules in Blue Prism

Tags: rpa, blueprism

How do I retrieve the timetable/calendar of future schedules (as seen in the control tab) from Blue Prism?

In the Blue Prism SQL database I've been able to find some tables (such as *BPASchedule* and *BPAScheduleTrigger*, among others) related to scheduling but none of them seem to contain information about future timetable/calendar events. Is this information stored anywhere? If not, how can I programmatically reconstruct the timetable using the data available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blue Prism database stores only recurrence pattern data for each schedule; it does not store the timetable itself — rather, it calculates the timetable on the fly.

The following SQL query returns all the **data** we need to programmatically **reconstruct** the Blue Prism timetable ourselves:

```
SELECT bpaschedule.name,
       period,
       unittype AS periodunit,
       startdate,
       enddate,
       startpoint,
       endpoint,
       COALESCE(workingweek, dayset) AS dayset
FROM   bpascheduletrigger
       LEFT JOIN bpaschedule ON ( bpascheduletrigger.scheduleid = bpaschedule.id )
       LEFT JOIN bpacalendar ON bpacalendar.id = calendarid
WHERE  retired = 0
       AND bpaschedule.NAME IS NOT NULL
       AND ( enddate > Getdate() OR enddate IS NULL )
       AND ( ( unittype = 0 AND startdate > Getdate() ) OR unittype != 0 )
ORDER  BY scheduleid
```

(This query retrieves only active schedules that will occur at least once in the future).

**Example Output**

| name | period | periodunit | startdate | enddate | startpoint | endpoint | dayset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Process A | 10 | 6 | 2019-03-08 23:00:00.000 | NULL | 30600 | 66000 | 4 |
| Process B | 10 | 6 | 2019-04-11 07:15:00.000 | NULL | 25500 | 29700 | 62 |
| Process C | 1 | 2 | 2020-07-22 15:59:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 86399 | 62 |
| Process D | 1 | 3 | 2020-05-08 16:50:00.000 | 2021-06-06 14:20:00.000 | 0 | 86399 | 32 |
| Process E | 1 | 3 | 2020-04-06 08:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 86399 | 2 |
| Process F | 1 | 3 | 2020-04-07 06:45:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 86399 | 4 |

The meaning of many of the columns is rather opaque so let's dissect them...

#### Period

The *period* column denotes the period time in the associated period units.

*Period unit* takes one of seven values, as below:

```
0 = Once
1 = Hour
2 = Day
3 = Week
4 = Month
5 = Year
6 = Minute
```

A *period* of 17 and a *periodunit* of 6 therefore means "scheduled every 17 minutes".

#### Start and end date

For **all** schedules these values denote the datetime range in which the schedule is valid.

Then, depending on other parameters, the time from *startdate* may denote the time the schedule runs at. *startdate* is used like this when *period* = 1 (or, when *startpoint* and *endpoint* are 0 and 83999 respectively).

*enddate* for a schedule is `NULL` when the schedule is set to never expire.

#### Start and end point

When a schedule is setup as `Hourly / Minutely`, an intraday start and end time must be specified (in the Blue Prism *Control Room*). *Startpoint* and *endpoint* represent these times, in seconds, from 00:00.

Process B has a *startpoint* of **25500** seconds. This equates to 7 hours, 4 minutes and 59 seconds — in other words, the process first starts at **07:04:59AM**.

#### Dayset

Dayset represents the integer value of a **bitset**, where individual bits each correspond to a day of the week:

```
None = 0
Sun = 1
Mon = 2
Tue = 4
Wed = 8
Thu = 16
Fri = 32
Sat = 64
```

A dayset of 62 (as in the table) therefore corresponds to Mon-Fri (the integer value of a bitwise OR of `Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri`); the dayset of a schedule running on Mon and Thu only would be 18 (2+16).

---

Taking all this together then, row 1 in natural language equates to:

> Process A runs every 10 minutes between 08:30:00 and 18:20:00 on Tuesdays indefinitely (no end date).

...and the last row equates to:

> Process E runs every week on Friday, at 8AM indefinitely.

---

Now it's up to you translate the logic discussed here into code that turns Blue Prism schedule entries from the SQL query into programmatically queryable recurring (calendar) events. Consider using a library that performs *recurrence calculations*; such a library should make it easy to answer questions like these:

> When does this schedule next run?

> Which schedules run between date1 and date2?

Comment: thank you this was absolutely stellar in solving my issue.