# How to find/calculate future schedules in Blue Prism - A follow up

Tags: rpa, blueprism

I have a question regarding how to calculate future schedules in Blue Prism. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824157/how-to-find-calculate-future-schedules-in-blue-prism) extremely helpful but as I dug into doing this myself there seemed to be one gap that is not answered in the article.

Say I have a weekly schedule that is to run once a week on the Last working day of a calendar that runs Mon-Wed.

The Query would return a period of 1, a period unit of 3, start and end dates, the start and end points are 0 and 86399 respectively, and the dayset is 28 corresponding to Mon-Wed (due to the Calendar).

My question, how would I know from these points that I am supposed to only run on the last working day, Wed, rather than Mon or Tues? Normally I could use the start date and add weeks until I get to the current week, but in this case the start date is on a Monday but the since the last working day is specified, it would only start the schedule on a Wednesday. Is there another piece of data I am missing or would I have to avoid creating a schedule like this?

[Example of Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Its76.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine Weekly and Monthly Schedules (Does not apply to other schedule types) that have triggers such as:

- The first/last working day in calendar
- The first/last/second/third/fourth/fifth *insert day of week* of the month

The SQL Query from the linked article must be appended to add the column "nthofmonth"

```
SELECT bpaschedule.name,
       period,
       unittype AS periodunit,
       startdate,
       enddate,
       startpoint,
       endpoint,
       COALESCE(workingweek, dayset) AS dayset,
       nthofmonth
FROM   bpascheduletrigger
       LEFT JOIN bpaschedule ON ( bpascheduletrigger.scheduleid = bpaschedule.id )
       LEFT JOIN bpacalendar ON bpacalendar.id = calendarid
WHERE  retired = 0
       AND bpaschedule.NAME IS NOT NULL
       AND ( enddate > Getdate() OR enddate IS NULL )
       AND ( ( unittype = 0 AND startdate > Getdate() ) OR unittype != 0 )
ORDER  BY scheduleid
```

This value is used to determine the value of first/last/second/third/fourth/fifth. If the schedule is not a weekly or month schedule, or your monthly/weekly schedule does not use the triggers that require selecting one of these values, then the value of this column will be 0.

```
Not used  =  0
Last  =  -1
First  =  1
Second  =  2
Third  =  3
Fourth  =  4
Fifth  =  5
```

As an example, a query returning a period of 1, a period unit of 3, start and end dates, the start and end points are 0 and 86399 respectively, a dayset is 28 corresponding to Mon-Wed (due to the Calendar), and nthofmonth of -1 would correspond to a weekly schedule running on the last working day of the selected calendar(weekly on Wednesday).

If the nthofmonth value was 1, it would be Weekly on Mondays.

Another example, a calendar running monthly on the 3rd Tuesday of the month would correspond to period of 1, a period unit of 4, start and end points of 0 and 86399 respectively, a dayset of 4, and nthofmonth of 3.